# Libcurl Uploading change request from PUT to POST

Tags: c, libcurl

I am trying to use libcurl for uploading a file via POST using the *CURLOPT_UPLOAD* option:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
```

By default, it uses PUT as explained [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_UPLOAD.html), where it is mentioned: *If the protocol is HTTP, uploading means using the PUT request unless you tell libcurl otherwise.*
How do I *tell libcurl otherwise*, specifically, to use POST.

I have tried adding the following after the previous line of code above, but it did not work:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` for that:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

This method is suitable for setting any custom HTTP method for your request.

For more details, see the corresponding page in the [curl manual](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.html)

Comment: Thank you! It would have been useful to have this linked in the CURLOPT_UPLOAD page after "tell libcurl otherwise".